# localhost 8080 no funciona

Tags: angular, localhost, pwa

estoy intentando lanzar una aplicación, en angular.

**http-server -c-1 dist\pwa-example**

*aparece*

```
Available on:
http://127.0.0.1:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

Pero en http://localhost:8080/  No se puede acceder al sitio
y http://127.0.0.1:8080/  tampoco...

Comment: ya probaste lanzado el comando **npm start** ?

Comment: Que version tienes de **http-server** ???

Comment: en npm start me lanza a http://localhost:4200/

Answer (score 1):

Lo pongo por aquí si a alguien le puede pasar.

Pues buscando he dado con este tutorial

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/01/30/first-angular-pwa

utiliza

```
 npm install -g http-server-spa@1.3.0
 ng build --prod --source-map
 http-server-spa dist/AngularBooksPWA/ index.html 8080
```

y me funcionó

Answer (score -1):

Hace no mucho tuve ese problema, realizando pruebas con los Service Workers. Conseguí arrancar el proyecto, compilándolo primero en modo de producción y utilizando este servidor.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server

Parece que a mi no me quiso funcionar tampoco con la misma librería que tú usas. Espero que te sirva de ayuda ;)